# Is there any clean way to capture all SQL Server queries on a database?

Tags: sql-server

I'm using Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP1) and need to capture and log all queries that run on my database. What's the best solution for this?

Comment: This is pretty broad, but here's a starting point. https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/243484/capture-sql-server-queries-without-third-party-tooling-and-without-using-depreca

Comment: Profiler. Standard SQL Server tool.